# std::function для шаблонных функций

Tags: c++

Есть такой класс.

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

template<class T>
class test_class
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void value(T v)
    {
        std::function<T(double, int)> func = std::bind(&test_class::test, this, _1, _2, v);
        func(45.6, 8);
    }

    template<class T>
    T test(double d, int i, T t)
    {
        return T();
    }
};

int main()
{
    test_class<int> ts;
    int a = 45;
    ts.value(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Имеются ошибки компиляции:

1) `"std::bind": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция`;

2) `std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...): не удается составить аргумент шаблон для "_Fx"`.

Как правильно составить конструкцию?

**P. S.:** код не несет смысла, просто пример.

Comment: @Abyx можно пример пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня Visual Studio 2017 скомпилировала так:

```
std::function<T(double, int)> func = std::bind(&test_class::test<T>, this, _1, _2, v);
```

Более строгий gcc заметил совпадение имён внешнего и внутреннего шаблонных параметров и потребовал ещё убрать `template<class T>` у внешнего класса и в объявлении `test_class<int> ts;` убрать шаблонный параметр.

(Или можно убрать `template<class T>` у функций-членов, тогда строчка с `std::bind` пройдёт и в вашем варианте.)

---

Корень проблемы, насколько я понимаю, в том, что `std::bind` требуется на вход функция (точнее — callable object), а не шаблон функции. А вы передаёте именно шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, полезно очень про корень проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, очевидная грубая ошибка

```
template<class T>
class test_class
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void value(T v)
    ...
```

Имя параметра внешнего шаблона запрещается переиспользовать в качестве имени параметра шаблона-члена. Так что внутренний параметр придется переименовать

```
template<class T>
class test_class
{
public:
    template<class U>
    void value(U v)
    ...
    template<class U>
    U test(double d, int i, U t)
    ...
```

Во-вторых, в реализации функции `value` упоминается шаблон `test_class::test` без указания шаблонных аргументов. Это ни в какие ворота не лезет. Для шаблона `test_class` аргумент можно не указывать и тогда `test_class` в этом контексте будет расцениваться как `test_class<T>`. Однако для шаблона `test` указание аргумента обязательно. Если я правильно понимаю ваши намерения это должен быть `U`

```
template<class U>
void value(U v)
{
    std::function<U(double, int)> func = std::bind(&test_class::test<U>, this, _1, _2, v);
    func(45.6, 8);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за найденные ошибки. Про вторую ошибку уже понял, а вот про первую..как то забыл я про это совсем, также, спасибо.